# Как сделать, чтобы кнопка двигалась вместе со страницей, когда палец пользователя перемещает страницу?

Tags: android, button, android-viewpager

У меня ViewPager с двумя customViews. Также у меня есть класс, который отвечает за навигацию (кнопки и точки навигации). Итак, у моих customView есть кнопка. Как я могу заставить эту кнопку двигаться вместе с прокруткой, когда палец пользователя перемещает страницу?. Т е , когда первое представление viewPager перемещается влево (т.е. мы переходим на вторую страницу), кнопка перемещается тоже влево на второй странице.

navigationClass:

```
public class NavigationView extends LinearLayout {
    private Button button;

    public NavigationView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NavigationView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation, this, true);
        button = v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

   }
```

adapter class:

```
public PagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NotNull final ViewGroup container, int position) {

        navigationPoint = navigationView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        navigationPoint.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        navigationPoint.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);

        final FirstView firstView = new FirstView(context);
        View view = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                view = firstView;
                break;
            case 1:
                view = SecondCustomView.getView(context, container);
                break;
        }
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NotNull View view, @NotNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

activity class:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        pagerAdapter.setNavigationView(navigationView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Трудно понять, желаемый результат. Попробуйте приложить gif или схему от руки. И непонятно в чем собственно проблема

Comment: @Sergei Buvaka, обновила свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то типа такого:

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        button.setTranslationX(-positionOffsetPixels);
    }
});
```

А дальше надо играть с этими x-ами. Проблема в том, что ширина кнопки не нулевая и при скроллинге кнопка ваша должна раздвоиться, т.е. в какой-то момент и слева хвост должен торчать будет и справа. Просто перемещением кнопки вы такого не добьетесь. Видимо нужно две кнопки, тогда проще, одна в -x уходит, другая в ширину пейджера - x. А если скроллинг в обе стороны, то и три кнопки уже нужно (выглядит проще, чем две менять местами).

Comment: так в этом случае кнопка просто сразу сместится после запуска программы, а не при переходе на вторую страницу, нет?

Comment: Почему вы так решили? Кнопка будет на месте пока вы не будете менять страницы. https://ibb.co/Fb4rppH Попробуйте.

Comment: спасибо. я попробую

Answer (score 0):

Как мне кажется ваша кнопка находится не там где ей положено быть, чтобы она могла свайпаться вместе со страницей.

В вашем примере она находится в Активити в которой находится ViewPager и живет отдельной жизнью. Она не может свайпаться вместе с экранами ViewPager-а.

- Вы конечно можете это реализовать руками, но это нетривиальная задача, а вероятнее всего - ненужная.

Более простым и правильным вариантом будет поместить эту кнопку в макет вложенных в ViewPager фрагментов.

Если я не прав - приложите XML разметку, чтоб можно было нагляднее посмотреть где находится ваша кнопка

Comment: Вы правы, кнопка находитя в Активити, там же и ViewPager. Смысл в том, что бы листенер ViewPager-а получал информацию, что палец дотронулся до экрана и перемещает первую страницу влево, и в этот момент кнопка также начала свое движение

Comment: Так а почему не переместить кнопку внутри ViewPager-а? То что вы хотите сделать конечно можно, но это не просто и тут может быть много багов

Comment: потому что эта кнопка понадобится еще для других вьюх. поэтому я сделала кнопку и навигационные точки в отдельном CustomView.

Comment: Тогда вам надо вешать на viewPager скролл листенер и двигать эту кнопку руками, потом убирать ее из одного края и добавлять в другой.

Comment: именно руками? а если анимацию сделать на пермещение ?

Comment: Ну анимация это и есть руками. Вами нужно будет обработать все кейсы. Например пользователь начал тянуть и отпустил и страница вернулась обратно. Там очень много подводных камней всплывет. Посмотрите в сторону Motion Layout, может он вам поможет. А ещё лучше попробуете сделать это по другому все же. Ну или напишите какую-то свою каcтомную View. Вариантов много, но все они лч непростые

Comment: Я так и думала) спасибо!